# Select two columns group by (city,sku) , but just show the top 5 registers by (city)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to do a query to show the top seller products group by city.
The "trap" is, I just can show the top 5 by city:

I start using this query:

```
    select  ORD.shipping_address_city city,  ORDL.sku, sum(ORDL.price) SALES
    from database.ORDER ORD
         inner join database.ORDER_LINE ORDL on ORD.ID = ORDL.order_id
    WHERE shipping_address_city is not null
    group by ORD.shipping_address_city, ORDL.sku
    order by ORD.shipping_address_city,  SALES desc , ORDL.sku
```

This query is showing me a result like that:

```
city        sku             SALES
New York    FOUN-SUN-08     4225
New York    FOUN-SUN-07     3900
New York    FOUN-BTR-08     3462.5
New York    FOUN-SUN-09     3325
New York    GEMM-BTR-08     2977.5
New York    JO-BLE-09       2731.25
New York    DEM-BLK-08      2730
New York    GEMM-SBL-08     2675
New York    FOUN-BTR-07     2300
New York    GEMM-SBL-07     2065
New York    LINE-SBL-07     2035.5
Malibu      JO-HAZ-07       95
Malibu      STUD-SAB-07     68
Malibu      NOR-LIT-07      65
Malibu      NOR-TAR-07      65
Malibu      GEMM-BTR-07     50
Malibu      GEMM-SBL-07     50
Malibu      RILE-BTR-07     50
Malibu      RILE-SBL-07     50
Malibu      SOLI-NO17-07    45
Toronto     SOLI-NO19-06    100
Toronto     MUN-UTY-T13     68
Toronto     BJN-WOLF-T11/12 55
Toronto     FOUN-TRO-06     50
Toronto     MB-LIL-06       50
Toronto     KTKE-BTR-T13    44
Toronto     MINI-ZINK-T13   44
```

But I need to show just the top 5 by city, like that:

```
city        sku             SALES
New York    FOUN-SUN-08     4225
New York    FOUN-SUN-07     3900
New York    FOUN-BTR-08     3462.5
New York    FOUN-SUN-09     3325
New York    GEMM-BTR-08     2977.5
Malibu      JO-HAZ-07       95
Malibu      STUD-SAB-07     68
Malibu      NOR-LIT-07      65
Malibu      NOR-TAR-07      65
Malibu      GEMM-BTR-07     50
Toronto     SOLI-NO19-06    100
Toronto     MUN-UTY-T13     68
Toronto     BJN-WOLF-T11/12 55
Toronto     FOUN-TRO-06     50
Toronto     MB-LIL-06       50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

I assume your initial query properly reflects your business logic - so I didn't want to touch it - rather I propose to wrap your code with below (with exception for ORDER BY which I moved out to apply to final output)

```
SELECT sale.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY sales DESC LIMIT 5) top_cities FROM (

    -- start of your initial query here
    select  ORD.shipping_address_city city,  ORDL.sku, sum(ORDL.price) SALES
    from database.ORDER ORD
         inner join database.ORDER_LINE ORDL on ORD.ID = ORDL.order_id
    WHERE shipping_address_city is not null
    group by ORD.shipping_address_city, ORDL.sku
    -- end of your initial query here

  ) t
  GROUP BY city
) t, UNNEST(top_cities) sale 
-- ORDER BY city, sales DESC, sku
```

Note: obviously above approach can be applied directly to your initial query - but I am leaving it to you

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions:

```
select c.* except (seqnum)
from (select ORD.shipping_address_city as city, ORDL.sku, sum(ORDL.price) as SALES,
             row_number() over (partition by shipping_address_city order by sum(ORDL.price) desc, ordl.sku) as seqnum
      from database.ORDER ORD join
           database.ORDER_LINE ORDL
           on ORD.ID = ORDL.order_id
      where shipping_address_city is not null
      group by ORD.shipping_address_city, ORDL.sku
     ) c
where seqnum <= 5;
order by ORD.city, SALES desc, ORDL.sku ;
```

Answer (score 0):

After look into the bigquery documentation I found the function  **row_number() over ()**.

So, with this, I did the following query and it is working now:

```
select city, sku, sales,countnumber  
from (
select  trim(ORD.shipping_address_city) as city,  ORDL.sku, sum(ORDL.price) SALES, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY trim(ORD.shipping_address_city) ORDER BY sum(ORDL.price) DESC) countnumber
from database.ORDER ORD
     inner join database.ORDER_LINE ORDL on ORD.ID = ORDL.order_id
WHERE shipping_address_city <> ""
group by ORD.shipping_address_city, ORDL.sku )
where countnumaber <= 5 
order by city,   SALES desc , sku, countnumaber
```

I will not delete my own question because I believe is possible to be helpful to someone in the future

Comment: it is important to realize difference between using ROW_NUMBER() version vs. ARRAY_AGG(with LIMIT). The first one is not scalable requires moving all data in respective partition/group into one node which frequently ends up with Resource Exceeded error for big volumed data. While second option is highly scalable and usually does not have this issue :o)

Comment: also, deleting your question like this one - is not considered as a good manner here as we applied some efforts to help you and answer. Rather you should vote up useful answers. and also accept the one that you feel best :o)

Comment: I said, I will not delete! ;)

Comment: sure - I saw :o) , just added extra reasoning